# Caustics options not show in 3.1 final

Tags: caustics

Caustics options not show in 3.1 final
Trying to enable this. Every tutorials shows it up under lights, and object/shading.
I am in Cycles. But still no option.
Official release of blender 3.1.

Any help on what i am doing wrong or has it moved?

THank you
gary

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled by it myself. 3.1-alpha does have caustics and no extra configuration is needed for them to be used. However, the final release doesn't seem to have it. Files generated in 3.1-alpha with caustics open and render in 3.1 but without caustics.

Answer (score 4):

A build version that included caustics was D13533 submitted on December 18, and you can find it in the Blender Build archives.

Caustics did not make the cut for the official release of 3.1  according to the developer thread.  You can follow it if you are interested in the progress of the feature:

https://developer.blender.org/D13533

Comment: Indeed, thanks, the relevant comment is this, for those in a hurry https://developer.blender.org/D13533#381586

Comment: Wait, it is not clear. Was it dropped or deferred to a future version?

Comment: It has been added to Blender 3.2 (official).

Answer (score 3):

As of 3.2.0 beta there's limited caustics in shadows of refractive objects:

[Release Notes 3.2 Cycles (fourth bit down)](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.2/Cycles)